# IOS (Swift) How to explore persistent file(s) during debug session?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

First post on StackOverflow, after extensively using it for a long time.

I'm building a small app (just to lear swift), and I have troubles with making some data persistent. I use NSCoding to achieve that. The problem is that when saving, the function `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject()` return `true` (so apparently it worked), but when, later, I try to retrieve these saved informations, the result of `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile()` is `nil`.

Without posting all my code, I was just wondering if it were possible to explore the file in which persistent data are stored during a debug session. That would allow me to check whether I have a problem with the saving or the loading part of the process, and see if the data are indeed stored in the right file.

Thanks,

Lb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithFile:), you get a `nil` with `unarchiveObjectWithFile` when there is no file at the mentioned path. I would advise to check your file path where you are archiving and saving your object.

As for the debugging, follow this:

1. Print the file path when you are archiving and saving the object. So in this `NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myObject, toFile: filePath)` print `filePath`.
2. Open your `terminal` app and execute `open <filePath>` command to open the file path where data is being saved.
3. Check out if your data file is created in there with right archiving.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

It helped finding out that actually there was a problem of types between the stored data and the data that I was trying to retrieve.

It was indeed useful to check the file content, I would have expected such a built-in function within xCode... But anyway, thanks, problem solved.

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers :)!